# jQuery to only run when mobile CSS has loaded?

Tags: jquery, css

I am loading my mobile only CSS using a media query such as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/includes/css/mobile.css" />
```

but in addition to these CSS changes I also need to reorder part of the HTML such as

```
$('#moveOne').after($('#theOther');
```

I only want this move to be actioned if the browser has definitely loaded the mobile.css. So I thought of adding some odd CSS value inside mobile.css and then checking the value of it like so

```
if($'#notVisible').css('color') == 'red') {
    $('#moveOne').after($('#theOther');
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think, this is a good way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you are doing is absolutely good.

But a more logical way would be setting `width` instead of `color`.

```
if($'#notVisible').width() == '500px') {
    $('#moveOne').after($('#theOther');
}
```

Also, you can try [matchMedia.js](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/)

Look here [Using_media_queries_from_code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_media_queries_from_code) too.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the same logic as your media query

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 480) {
    $('#moveOne').after($('#theOther');
}
```